# Image attachment as first item (left aligned) in NSAttributed string

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel, nsattributedstring

I am trying to add an image to a UILabel using a `NSAttributedString` with a `NSTextAttachment`

```
func attributedString(string:String)->NSAttributedString {
    let label:NSMutableAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString()

    let string = NSAttributedString(string: string)
    let attachment = NSTextAttachment()
    attachment.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "WaterIcon")
    let imageString = NSAttributedString(attachment: attachment)

    label.append(string)
    label.append(imageString)

    return label
}
```

[image]

when I switch

```
    label.append(imageString)
    label.append(string)
```

… which is what I want regarding the order, the image doesn't show up at all :-(

How can I add the image as first item in the string?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You code works just fine for me with the two `append` statements swapped:

[image]

Perhaps there is a problem with how your label is sized/positioned, or how you are assigning the attributed string to the label. But you have not shown any of that part of your code, so who knows what you're doing wrong?

Comment: Thanks so much for double checking. I just noticed the issue in fact wasn't in the code. I used a Template Image without applying a tint (does this even work within NSTextAttachment…?). So the image was at the right place but it didn't visually show up. But I could see it enabling "Color Blended Layers" in the Simulator. Thank you for helping me find the issue!

Comment: Yes, often a highly simplified test reveals that the problem is not what you think it is! Glad to help. Your use of the Color Blended Layers setting was a clever idea.